# Error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I can't find the error here, anyone can help me?

```sql
CREATE TABLE Aluno
(
    nr_rgm number (8) not null,
    nm_aluno varchar2 (40) not null,
    nm_mae varchar2 (40),
    nm_pai varchar2 (40),
    dt_nascimento date,
    id_sexo char(1),
    constraint aluno_nr_rgm_pk primary key (nr_rgm)
)
 
CREATE TABLE Matricula
(
    nr_rgm number (8) not null FOREIGN KEY,
    cd_classe number (8) not null,
    dt_matricula date,
)
  
CREATE TABLE Classe
(
    cd_classe number (8) not null PRIMARY KEY,
    nr_anoletivo number (4),
    nr_serie number (2),
    sg_turma varchar2 (2),
    cd_escola number (6),
    cd_grau number (2),
    cd_periodo number (2),
)

ALTER TABLE Matricula ADD FOREIGN KEY (cd_classe) REFERENCES Classe(cd_classe)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. At first glance I worry about the commas at the ends of the second and third CREATE statements. If that's not it, please edit your post with the complete error message.

Comment: Run the code one statement at a time.  If you still can't figure out the problem, comment out parts of the table definition.

Comment: second create statement and third create state has a unnecessary ‘,’

Comment: Remove the last `,` before your closing parentheses for the second and third CREATE TABLE statement. And add `;` to end each statement

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is wrong `nr_rgm number (8) not null FOREIGN KEY` in table `Matricula` because it does not specify the external key table. The following code works correctly.

```
CREATE TABLE Aluno
(
    nr_rgm number (8) not null,
    nm_aluno varchar2 (40) not null,
    nm_mae varchar2 (40),
    nm_pai varchar2 (40),
    dt_nascimento date,
    id_sexo char(1),
    constraint aluno_nr_rgm_pk primary key (nr_rgm)
)
 
CREATE TABLE Matricula
(
    nr_rgm number (8) not null,
    cd_classe number (8) not null,
    dt_matricula date,
)
  
CREATE TABLE Classe
(
    cd_classe number (8) not null PRIMARY KEY,
    nr_anoletivo number (4),
    nr_serie number (2),
    sg_turma varchar2 (2),
    cd_escola number (6),
    cd_grau number (2),
    cd_periodo number (2),
)

ALTER TABLE Matricula ADD FOREIGN KEY (cd_classe) REFERENCES Classe(cd_classe) 
ALTER TABLE Matricula ADD FOREIGN KEY (nr_rgm) REFERENCES Aluno(nr_rgm)
```